# Can I connect to BLE without the device advertise?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

**the BLE device only advertise when button is pressed**

I think i don't completely understand the paring protocol...and i cant find an answer to my problem:

My application scans for devices , upon advertising i connect to it, discover it's services and register to get notifications and indications from it (which i get)... I do get the broadcasts for pairing request and pair.

when I turn the BLE device off, and then on and try to get it's notifications nothing happens! (I don't get notifications or indications  )until I press the advertising button which triggers the hole process again.

Is this hoe its supposed to work? Whiteout advertising the devices will not be connected?

do I need to call device.connect() in a loop all the time that i'm not connected?

Many thanks to all answerers

Desperate me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually what solved my problem was the second parameter in the connectGatt function... which means autoConnect..

device.connectGatt(context, **true**, mGattCallback);

Answer (score 0):

You can’t create a connection between two devices without using advertisements.

There is an interval after each advertisement in which the device listens for connection requests. So, you can connect directly without scanning for the advertisements, but the device must be advertising in order to be able to connect to it.